# Async task registered by RegisterAsyncTask is not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, webforms

I am editing some legacy WebForms application and I am trying to register async call in data grid row updating event handler. Code looks like this:

```
private void grid_RowUpdating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(async () => await DoSomethingAsync()));
}
```

Unfortunately async method is never called. Even when I call ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks nothing happens. I set Async="true" for page in aspx file.

I would like to know why task is not fired. In examples I have seen RegisterAsyncTask being used always in Page_Load. I am not sure if it is too late to registered task during control event.

Update:

I am targeting framework 4.5 in my web config. Under system.web:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="131072" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Update 2:

If I place RegisterAsyncTask into Page_Load event task is fired. This leads me to conclusion that it is too late to register task in event handler. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation about this.

Comment: Are you targeting .NET 4.5, and have set the runtime in `web.config` to 4.5?

Comment: Yes updating my question to include this information.